# variable value inside $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a range of textboxes named from `fa-select-1` to `fa-select-8` and I need to echo content from each of these textboxes using `$_POST['fa-select-1'];`

Currently I am using separate code for each id and echoing it like

```
$fa1 = $_POST['fa-select-1'];
echo = "fa-select-1 value is $fa1";
```

I am doing the same from `fa1` to `fa8`. I am changing this do using a while loop.

```
$x=1; 
while($x<=8)
    {
$fa = $_POST['fa-select-1'];
echo "fa-select-$x value is $test".PHP_EOL;
$x++;
}
```

but here I need to loop through  `$_POST['fa-select-1'];` to `$_POST['fa-select-8'];` in  `$fa = $_POST['fa-select-1'];`. How can I do that ? in javascript i can mention it like `$('#fa-select-'+x)` if x is javascript variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate:

```
$x=1; 
while($x<=8)
{
    $fa = $_POST["fa-select-$x"];
    echo "fa-select-$x value is $test".PHP_EOL;
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: No errors. Getting output like `fa-select-1 value is`   but not showing actual value

Comment: where does the $test variable come from?

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw You should ask the OP, I just copied the original code.

Comment: My bad..There was a typo while defining the variable..corrected it and its working fine now..Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Just use the concatenation operator (which is a '.' in PHP as opposed to JS where it is a '+' (for strings)):

```
$_POST['fa-select-' . $x];
```

You can also directly embed `$x` in the **double-quoted** string:

```
$_POST["fa-select-$x"];
```

Despite that, you should escape the output in the case some evil user sends HTML in the data:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fa-select-' . $x]);
```

Answer (score 1):

please try with this ...

```
<?php
$x=1; 
while($x<=8){
    $fa = $_POST["fa-select-$x"];
    echo "fa-select-$x value is $fa <br />";
    $x++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
    $fa = $_POST['fa-select-' . $i];
    echo 'fa-select-' . $x . 'value is ' . $test . PHP_EOL;
}
```